# Hair goes out of place when moving the armature!

Tags: rigging, particles, hair

So... The I have a rigged model with clothes and all, particle hair that follows the model, everything seemed to be okay until I moved the right arm!

[image: As you can see, there are a couple of hairs just floating around]

If I reset the position everything goes back to place, but as soon as I move that arm in pose mode, those hairs go crazy. Everything else seems to be okay, I have the armature modifier avobe the particles, I don't know what to do, I'm actually pretty new to blender so It'd be awesome if someone could help ;v;

Comment: If you are new to Blender, go to page 4 in this scrapbook link here. https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13UpIjJEE7Oa7x5BiMsjXGW5CGOTDF03-SocRYi4Babs There, you will find all the best playlists for absolute beginners wishing to learn 2.8x. They will pull you up fast on Blender and afterwards leave you with a swollen brain within short time. Page 5 is for those wishing to learn outdated version 2.7x.

Comment: You might want to visit Pinterest for boards on Blender. At Pinterest, there are TONS of gems for Blenderheads, stuff like alpha brushes, textures, nodes, addons, etc. Whenever I get stuck on topology during modeling, I always go to Pinterest where I find tons of topology ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You should enter in weight paint mode and see if that arm is affecting other parts in the mesh